# How do you reverse the axis and set the zero position for a polar plot in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

When using Matplotlib's polar plot, the default zero position for the theta axis is or the right with the angle increasing counter-clockwise, as shown in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/polar_demo.html).

[image]

How do you specify the zero position and reverse the direction of increasing theta?  As of writing this, the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.polar.html) is relatively limited.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The axis methods `set_theta_zero_location` and `set_theta_direction` allow you to specify the zero location and the direction of increasing theta, respectively.  Here is a modified version of the [Matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/polar_demo.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(theta, r)
ax.set_rmax(2)
ax.set_rticks([0.5, 1, 1.5, 2])  # less radial ticks
ax.set_rlabel_position(-22.5)  # get radial labels away from plotted line
ax.grid(True)

# ---- mod here ---- #
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")  # theta=0 at the top
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)  # theta increasing clockwise
# ---- mod here ---- #

ax.set_title("A line plot on a polar axis", va='bottom')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that for a quiverplot, these methods currently produce [strange results (see GitHub issue)](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5888).