# How do you reverse the axis and set the zero position for a polar plot in Julia / Plots?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

When using Julia / plots heatmap polar plot, the default zero position for the theta axis is or the right ("East") with the angle increasing counter-clockwise, as shown in this example.

[How do you reverse the axis and set the zero position for a polar plot in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805975/how-do-you-reverse-the-axis-and-set-the-zero-position-for-a-polar-plot-in-matplo)

I want to have the zero in the "North" position and have a clockwise orientation. How can I do this ?

Thanks